# Trying to understand prescaling voltage for ADC with least error

Tags: adc, voltage-measurement, accuracy

I'm teaching myself EE while designing a 12V DC battery monitor. I'm using a pair of Hall-effect sensors to track charge & load current and looking for the best way to measure the voltage. [An ATmega32u4 will take successive reads with the ADC, compute a 1-second average, and pass that up over USB for logging and analysis.]

The issue of error with ADC really has me spooked. It is essential that I produce meaningful data. There's so many error sources—both in my circuit and in the ADC—that it feels like playing wack-a-mole in the dark. I'm reading lots about calibrating the ADC's reference, but the first step is to pick a method for scaling the input.

My voltage window is 10-15V, specifically a range from 10.5V to 14.4V (3.9V). I came up with two approaches that (hopefully) do what I want:

1. A 10V Zener diode on the inverting input of a differential op-amp. Rejecting 10V, my range becomes 0.5V to 4.4V (3.9V) and uses nearly the whole range of my ADC.
2. A 20k : 10k voltage divider. Scaled down 3x, my range becomes 3.5V to 4.8V (1.3V)

I wanted to prove to myself which method would render the best granularity. Since I can also obtain 12-bit accuracy by adding four reads and shifting the result, I compared four possibilities: (assuming ADC ref is 5.0V)

- method 1, 0.5-4.4V @10-bit is 800 steps: 4.88mV/step [#3]
- method 1, 0.5-4.4V @12-bit is 3606 steps: 1.22mV/step [#1]
- method 2, 3.5-4.8V @10-bit is 266 steps: 14.65mV/step [#4]
- method 2, 3.5-4.8V @12-bit is 1065 steps: 3.66mV/step [#2]

My question is, do my mV/step figures tell the whole story, or is there some kind of downside to #2 that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Well-written question. But did you look in the RELATED column when you created your question? I know there is an offset concern in your question, but apart from that, there are 3 duplicates addressing essentially the same topic, all with useful answers: see [Question1](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15295/shrinking-an-input-signal-for-the-adc?rq=1), or [Question2](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21017/how-to-convert-0-to-10v-analog-signal-to-0-to-2-5v-for-adc-input?rq=1) or [Question3](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/voltage-dividers-and-adcs)

Comment: While those questions cover the same topic, my question was specifically about whether my calculations of granularity were accurate and tell the whole story. I edited for clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The offset with the **zener** is of little use. The best zeners have a 1 % tolerance, which is 100 mV for a 10 V zener. On a 10-bit ADC this is a 20 count error, on a 12-bit ADC an 82 count error. You could trim the error away if you can measure the voltage accurately enough, but there are other factors. The [BZX84-A10](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/BZX84_SERIES.pdf) has an 8 mV/°C temperature coefficient, giving a 2 count error per °C change in temperature for the 10-bit ADC, and 7 counts for the 12-bit. Looks like it's better suited as thermometer than as voltage meter. When you use a 10 V zener you'll also need a higher voltage power supply.

The **resistance divider** will do much better. Resistors also have a tolerance, but at 25 ¢ a 0.1 % resistor is still affordable. (Better that 0.1 % becomes expensive quickly: a 0.05 % costs almost 1 dollar.) At 10-bit resolution that will give you a 1 count error, 4 counts at 12-bit. Temperature coefficient will be less of a problem if both resistors are from the same series and placed close to each other: since the divider is ratiometric resistance changes will cancel each other out.

The numbers indicate that a higher than 10-bit resolution is of little use; component tolerances and variations will cause extra bit to be unreliable. A few extra bits may help to increase noise immunity, though, by averaging a series of measurements, or using a sigma-delta ADC, which averages the input signal anyway.

There's also something more philosophical: we always want better, but why on earth would you want to know a 12 V battery's voltage to a precision of better than 10 mV. You'll have a hard time getting the required resolution, and you'll always be uncertain about that last digit.

The [ADS1000](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1000.pdf) is a low cost 12-bit ADC which will operate from a single 5 V supply.

Comment: Great answer! ADS1114 can come complete on a pcb module on ebay which may be more accessible for beginners. It's also has its own voltage reference and is not ratiometric to the supply unlike the ADS1000, which may be a benefit in this case.